# Can we use "not either" instead of "neither"?

Tags: grammaticality, conjunctions, negation

Can we use "not either" instead of "neither"?

For example, given that…

1. I don't like football
2. I don't like basketball

… which of the following are correct?

A. I like neither football nor basketball.

B. I don't like either football or basketball.

Comment: Both are grammatically correct, and both mean the same thing. The negative in (2) strips the _n-_ off _either_ and _or_.

Answer (score 2):

Note: you cannot say "I like not either football not or basketball"; that sentence is incorrect.

You can however say:

> I do not like football or basketball.

Comment: You still need to discuss "neither" vs. "not either," though.

Answer (score 0):

Both sound acceptable to me.  A is a textbook *neither…nor* construction.  B is just another way of stating "I don't like either sport", which is allowable.

Sentences A and B have slightly different connotations, though, due to the verb being affirmative in A and negative in B.  If I had to guess at a likely continuation for each sentence, I would say…

- I like neither football nor basketball. <sub><sup>*(Well then, what* do *you like?)*</sup></sub> Actually, I prefer hockey.
- I don't like either football or basketball.  <sub><sup>*(Tell me more about your dislike, then.)*</sup></sub> In fact, I'm not a fan of heavily commercialized team sports at all.

Comment: @sumelic I don't think I changed the meaning in Rev 3. The OP made a mess by altering the question in Rev 2.