# Is this correct " Neither do I like football nor basketball "?

Tags: grammaticality

Is it correct "  Neither do I like football nor basketball "???
What does it mean???

Can we say that in other words??

Comment: I would only say this after a sentence like *"I don't like baseball."*

Comment: @PeterShor - but wouldn't that be, "I don't like baseball. Neither do I like football **or** basketball." ?

Comment: Usually one question mark at the end of an interrogative sentence is enough. Could you please explain what you don't understand, show a minimum of research. For example, have you looked *neither* up in a dictionary? Have you looked at any of the thousands online English grammar websites that explain how to use "neither" and "nor"? Maybe you should [visit ELL](http://ell.stackexchange.com/). This question will be closed for being off-topic because it lacks research.

Comment: If you read this sentence somewhere, please say "where" and quote what was written before and after. http://english.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: @chasly: You're right: it should be *or* (although I can see *nor* if you paused after *football*).

Comment: No, all of these are incorrect. You are not allowed to dislike baseball, basketball *and* football.

Comment: @Ernest Tough! I for one thoroughly dislike all three of them. I'll take badminton, tennis, and volleyball any day of the week (and usually do, in fact).

Comment: Please do not ask the same or nearly the same question twice: http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/272619/is-this-sentence-grammaticaly-correct, http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/272540/can-we-use-not-either-instead-of-neither, http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/272478/how-can-we-coordinate-two-sentences-with-neither-in-this-example

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> "Neither do I like football nor basketball "

That doesn't sound like something a native speaker would say. I suggest

*I like neither football nor basketball.*

or

*I don't like football or basketball.*

or, if it is in response to a previous statement

John - "I don't like football or basketball."

Mary - "I don't like football or basketball either."

Comment: You should have posted this as a comment.

Comment: And your reason?

Comment: See my comments under the OP.

Comment: I see the comments. They are fair. I'm just asking for an explicit reason this should be a comment rather than an answer.

Comment: Because the question as it stands is off-topic. Questions asking "is this correct?" should be discouraged. Good questions will obtain better answers.

Comment: Does one say a statement?

Comment: @Lawrence - Good point. I'll edit.

Comment: It becomes grammatical with the tiniest of changes: “I don’t like baseball. Neither do I like football **or** basketball.”