# What follows "not either"? "Or" or "nor"?

Tags: grammar, negation

Consider the following sentence:

> I haven't heard from either you, (n)or her.

If I started my sentence with "I **have** heard from **neither** you" then the "nor" would follow. My doubts stem from the fact that I'm using negation (which suggests "nor") but I'm also using "not" ("have not") and "either" in the first part of the sentence which suggests "or" in the second part.

So which one is it?

Comment: No need to duplicate the negation in the prepositional phrase:  I haven't heard from either you **or** her. Or "I've heard from neither you nor her."

Comment: @TimR Sounds like an answer. Why don't you make it an official answer so I can accept it? ;)

Comment: There's [an existing question](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/272540/can-we-use-not-either-instead-of-neither) on whether "not either" is valid which concludes the same thing.

Comment: @NPS Because I expected the question to be closed as a duplicate.

Comment: @StuartF: I see nothing about ***either*** + ***nor*** on your link, but it *has* been asked about here before ELL was created, so I'm citing that as a dup, rather than voting to migrate.

Comment: Ah, yes, the "duplicates" that contain neither the same question, nor a direct answer to the "duplicate" question.

Comment: As one of the answers on that linked duplicate says, ***either...nor**, as per your question title is **never correct.*** As it happens, even the words ***as per your question title*** also work for this question as well as the original (it's syntactically irrelevant that ***either*** here is preceded by negating ***not***).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The writer at [Medium](https://medium.com/@writepractice/how-to-use-either-neither-or-and-nor-correctly-eb2a93b977cb) explains:

> *Either* is always paired with *or*, and *neither* is always paired with *nor*.
>
> *Neither*† indicates that the two ideas are linked together. It’s kind of like a negative conjunction. If you use *neither*, then make sure your sentence does not have
> any other negatives preceding it. If you prefer to use a negative,
> then you want to use either.
>
> - Jay had seen neither the snake nor the wasp’s nest on the [tree] ...
> - Jay had not seen either the snake or the wasp’s nest on the [tree] ....

†*Either* also links the two noun phrases / their referents. So correct are

- Jay had not seen [either the snake or the wasp’s nest] on the tree.
  and
- I haven't heard from [either you or her].

(braces to show cohesion within the either/or construction).